# Activity get stuck in Looper.java

Tags: android

One of my app's activities has ran into an issue; the problem seems to be an `asynk-task`, which get information from the server and generate a list of n elements in a view using that data, this, get the activity stuck in the white load screen instead of rendering the view.

No crashes or errors.

I can press back button and return to previous activity(Not freeze).

Android monitor show no cpu usage.

Here is the code.Is called at the end of `onCreate()`

```
new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {


                Document dom = null;

                Detalle detalle= getIntent().getParcelableExtra("pedido");
                try {
                    dom=DetalleToXml.getDom(detalle);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return dom;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                Document dom = (Document)o;
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                TableLayout t = (TableLayout) contentView.findViewById(R.id.grid_layout_pedido);
                t.removeAllViewsInLayout();

                final NodeList rows = dom.getElementsByTagName("row");

                if(rows.getLength() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(DetallesPedido.this, "La búsqueda no ha tenido resultados.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    for(int i = 0; i < rows.getLength(); i++){
                        Element e = (Element)rows.item(i);
                        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());

                        String rowid = UtilesDom.getValue(e, "rowid");
                        String articulo = UtilesDom.getValue(e, "articulo");
                        String precio_venta = UtilesDom.getValue(e, "precio_venta");
                        String cantidad = UtilesDom.getValue(e, "cantidad");
                        String descripcion = UtilesDom.getValue(e, "descripcion");


                        LinearLayout bigRow=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.pedido_detalle,null);

                        TextView tv=(TextView) bigRow.findViewById(R.id.detalle_row_textView1);
                        tv.setText(articulo);
                        tv=(TextView) bigRow.findViewById(R.id.detalle_row_textView3);
                        tv.setText(precio_venta);
                        tv=(TextView) bigRow.findViewById(R.id.detalle_row_textView2);
                        tv.setText(cantidad);
                        tv=(TextView) bigRow.findViewById(R.id.detalle_row_textView4);
                        tv.setText(descripcion);

                        try {
                            bigRow.setId(Integer.parseInt(rowid));
                        } catch (Exception e2) {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        bigRow.setTag(articulo);

                        bigRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                      @Override
                                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                                          String codigo = (String) v.getTag();
                                                          final Context context = v.getContext();
                                                          final int rowid = v.getId();

                                                          Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetalleFicha.class);
                                                          Bundle b = new Bundle(3);
                                                          b.putInt("rowid", rowid);
                                                          b.putInt("operation",UtilesABM.UPDATE);
                                                          b.putString("caller","DetallesPedido");
                                                          intent.putExtras(b);
                                                          intent.putExtra("pedido",getIntent().getParcelableExtra("pedido"));
                                                          loaded = false;
                                                          startActivity(intent);
                                                      }
                                                  }
                        );
                        //UtilesViews.setDefaultPadding(tv);
                        t.addView(bigRow);
                    }
                }
                super.onPostExecute(o);
            }
        }.execute(query);
```

By debugging i can reach the `Loop.java` class right after `execute()` and there is where gets stuck.
Any ideas of how to fix it or the cause of the problem?

Comment: Does it starts showing loading progress dialog?

Comment: @AndroDev No, just the start-up white screen

Answer (score 0):

You are performing very performance costly call

```
LinearLayout bigRow=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.pedido_detalle,null);
```

which can take too much time, and since you are doing it in onPostExecute call, which is being called on main thread, so main thread will gets blocked if number of rows are huge and app becomes unresponsive

Solution to this is, you can use recycler view

Comment: The loop run fine, no memory or cpu spikes, list is never bigger than 15, the activity as I said actually stops right after this, also I'm using same contraption in other activities with no problem